Trying to prevent some file extensions to be uploaded to my S3 bucket, doesn't seem to be working
I added the following policy to my S3 bucket, as I want to prevent those 4 file extensions from being uploaded anywhere in my bucket (folder, sub folder etc).
I am still able to upload files with a .exe extension, what am I doing wrong here?
{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
     "Statement": [
         {
             "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
             "Effect": "Deny",
             "Principal": "*",
             "Action": "s3:PutObject",
             "NotResource": [
                 "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*.bat",
                 "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*.exe",
                 "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*.cmd",
                 "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*.sh"
             ]
         }
     ]
 }


{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*.bat",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*.exe",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*.cmd",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*.sh"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Change NotResource to Resource, because NotResource mean that this policy should not apply for this formats (.bat, .exe, etc)
